# Eclipse giving internal error with VariablePlugin, what should I do?

Tags: java, eclipse

Every time I try to run a file I get this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching HelloWorld".
org/eclipse/core/variables/VariablesPlugin
```

I'm running just a simple hello world program to test. Eclipse 4.4.1 worked fine yesterday. I tried restarting the computer, tried updating Eclipse (no updates available). I tried Project ->Clean (and cleaned all projects).

I also have PyDev (so I could run Jython/Python files). I created a new project and made helloworld.py within that. When I tried running it with Python, I got this error(which is at least different): Unable to get project for the run

HelloWorld.java worked fine yesterday so I don't know what happened internally in Eclipse. What should I do?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any more detailed messages.

Comment: I looked at it and it did have different error messages, but I didn't know which ones of them were relevant. I ended up deleting Eclipse, and re-extracting it from its zip file, which seems to have fixed the problem.